# Magento 2: Multiple checkboxes in system.xml

Tags: magento2

I want to create a system config where you could tick the necessary weekdays, but this way:

```
<field id="days" translate="label" type="checkbox" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Days in the week</label>
                </field>
```

I only get one checkbox. Is there a way to have multiple checkboxes one below the other?

Answer (score 1):

By using multiselect field type, you can achieve your requirement.
Please see the below code:

```
 <field id="days" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
      <label>Days in the week</label>
      <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Weekdays</source_model>
 </field>
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific enough. I want to be able to select multiple days. With your solution you can only select one.

Comment: hold control and click to pick specific multiple days, hold shift to create a blanket monday to friday ect